# Adapt size JQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery

I have a dialog in JQuery, I call it with this script:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
        });

        $( "#newaircraft" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });
    });
```

The large is perfect, but the width isn´t fun. I don´t know why because I think it is automatic but only the large is automatic the width no.

Example screen: http://i50.tinypic.com/dwt7ur.png

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 500
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the height and width of your dialog using CSS :

Example :

```
#dialog{
   height:500px;
   width:500px;
}
```

or

```
#dialog{
   height:90%;
   width:90%;
}
```

or using `height` and `width` options of the JQueryUI Dialog widget :

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-height

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width